# Xcodebuild device desintation with variable exiting with code 127

Tags: ios, xcodebuild

I am trying to run xcodebuild command with a destination device that is discovered at runtime i.e. xcodebuild .... -destination "platform=iOS,name=$MY_DEVICE" ...

The command exits silently and the code is 127. If I change the name of the device to hardcoded string then the command works.

Any advice on how to input a variable in the destination option of xcodebuild?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the destination argument before the xcodebuild command.

```
MY_DEVICE="Tester iPhone"
DST="\"platform=iOS,name=$MY_DEVICE\""
echo "-destination $DST"
```

and then use that in the final command:

```
xcodebuild .... -destination $DST ...
```

Comment: Updated DST variable with speech marks as it was missing.